# Using for loop and if statement side by side C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, syntax

Can someone explain this syntax of using for and if side by side?

```
int min_dist = huge;
int v = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) if (!done[i]) {
    if (d[i] >= min_dist) continue;
    min_dist = d[i];
    v = i;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `side by side`?

Comment: That's just an if statement inside a for loop. What exactly don't you get? Put a newline before the "if" and it'll do exactly the same but be more readable. Add curly braces if you like to make it even more clear.

Comment: the if doesnt have to be on the next line, in most cases how much whitespace (including new lines) you put in is up to you.

Comment: It's just formatting.  The first if is the body the for loop.  The rest of the code is in the "true" body of the first if.

Comment: That's probably not the most intuitive way to write it, but it's just a loop that contains only an `if()` statement as its body. So the programmer went clever, and omitted the braces of the loop body.

Comment: Don't write code like that.

Comment: OT: The code is used in the Dijkstra algorithm to find the next closest vertex. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case of poorly indented and organized code. It is equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{  
  if (!done[i])
  {
    if (d[i] >= min_dist) continue;
    min_dist = d[i];
    v = i;
  }
}
```

Adding the block `{}` right after the `for` line makes it easier to read.

You can add another block for the second `if` statement to make it still easier.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  if (!done[i])
  {
    if (d[i] >= min_dist)
    {
      continue;
    }

    min_dist = d[i];
    v = i;
  }
}
```

You can simplify it to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  if (!done[i])
  {
    if (d[i] < min_dist)
    {
      min_dist = d[i];
      v = i;
    }
  }
}
```

The two `if`s can be combined to make it simpler still.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  if (!done[i] && d[i] < min_dist)
  {
    min_dist = d[i];
    v = i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It's not side by side. It's an `if` inside a `for`. The syntax of a `for` is

```
for(...)
  statement
```

And it just so happens that an `if` is also a statement. So your code is equivalent to this:

```
for(...)
  if() {
  }
```

Because white-spaces are pretty much ignored by the compilation process. It doesn't matter if there's a new line or not. It's still a statement. Just like it doesn't matter for the one-liner

```
if (d[i] >= min_dist) continue;
```

And if we don't omit those obviously crucial braces:

```
for(...) {
  if() {
  }
}
```

We'll be far less likely to be confused in the future.

Comment: And (what I think is relevant to OP); is the same as `for(...) if (...)` on one line.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the same:

```
int min_dist = huge;
int v = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    if (!done[i]) {
        if (d[i] >= min_dist) continue;
        min_dist = d[i];
        v = i;
    }
}
```

As an explanation, when you only have one statement inside a for or if, you don't need the brackets.

Comment: You don't *need* them; no. But you should still put them in (IMHO) as they are extremely helpful to the casual reader of your code - who *may* be a greenhorn not familiar with the details of C++ syntax. Write code for the readers, not for the compiler (the compiler will figure it out on its own if it is valid).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I agree with you, brackets really differentiate the scope, but is good know that they're not always necessary as you can come across with other code.

Answer (score 2):

The layout may fool you. It's just a for-loop with a single if-statement:

- for each item indexed by i
- if item i not done already, then proces item i in if-body
- else next item (in for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

I always find when looking at code I don't understand the best method is to rewrite it in a format which I find easier to read, in this case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    if (!done[i]) {
        if (d[i] >= min_dist) {
            continue;
        }
        min_dist = d[i];
        v = i;
    }
}
```

The fact that the `if` statement is beside the loop merely means that that is the expression to be resolved as the loop body (note this is always the case, blocks `{}` are also used). This `if` then has a body as well, by putting in the omitted blocks explicitly it is easier to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend about the loop without parenthesis, it can be used to execute a single block of statements. In this case the `if`statement groups all other statements in a pair of parenthesis, making them a single block.

Answer (score 0):

The **right way** to write this code is like this:

```
for (int i  0; i < N; ++i)
    if (!done[i] && d[i] < min_dist) {
        min_dist = d[i];
        v = i;
    }
```

Putting the `if` on the same line as the `for` just confuses things. As is having two `if` statements instead of one.

Comment: For extra clarity; add braces for the for loop as well.

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- for extra confusion, add braces to the for loop as well. <g> Seriously: this is more of a personal style issue. In my code I don't add redundant braces.

Comment: I agree that it's a style issue. But my personal experience is that newbies get less confused if you always add the braces. I myself find that unfamiliar code reads easier that way. So I (personally) am of the opinion that you should *always* just add the braces - required or not. But; it's a matter of taste..